# Unexpected token '*' Expected an opening '(' before a function's parameter list

Tags: javascript, ios, generator, ecmascript-5

iOS9 don't seems to like javascript generators `function*`. I'm currently trying to get rid of a promise problem on iOS and my code looks like this :

```
...

    myFunction: function() {
        return this.spawn(function*() {
            yield MyApp.function();
        });
        return;
    },
...
```

which leads to the following error on iOS 9:

> Unexpected token '*' Expected an opening '(' before a function's
>   parameter list

Do you know an alternative that would be compatible ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 supports generators. If you're stuck with iOS 9, then you'll have to implement your own *fake* generator. The generator protocol has the `next`, `return`, `throw`, and `[Symbol.iterator]` methods. You can implement only the ones you need. E.g., here's an implementation of `[Symbol.iterator]`:

```js
let createGenerator = values => () => ({
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let i = 0;
    return {
      next: () => ({
        value: values[i++],
        done: i > values.length
      }),
      // next
      // return
      // throw
    }
  }
});

let realGenerator = function*() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
};

let fakeGenerator = createGenerator([1, 2, 3, 4]);

console.log(...realGenerator());
console.log(...fakeGenerator());
```

Comment: But iOS 9 seems to really have a problem with the syntax `function*()` I'm not sure it would works : /

Comment: Hence, my solution (`createGenerator`) avoids `function*()`

Comment: ha ok, get it sorry